# Wordpress installation fails Ubuntu, PHP-FPM and Nginx

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, wordpress, php.ini

Wordpress installs without any issues. No error log in FPM, Nginx and WP-Debug. However it is not working. I believe the issue is related with FPM. When I carry all the WP code (no-change) into another host, it works even with the same db.

If I just install the Wordpress. The default admin account does not become available. The user is created in the MySQL but not as admin.

> Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

If I `systemctl reload php7.3-fpm` then install it, I can login as an Admin but page and post create gives the error below.

> PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'publicly_queryable'

After that if I `systemctl reload php7.3-fpm` then I can see page and post create but for a few minutes any second refresh. We are back to...

> PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'publicly_queryable'

Everything installed freshly. My setup:

- Ubuntu 16.04.6LTS
- Nginx 1.17.6
- Wordress 4.9 and 5.1 *tried both
- MySQL 5.5 and 8.0*tried both

I install PHP with the commands below.

`add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/nginx
apt-get install php7.3-bcmath php7.3-bz2 php7.3-cli php7.3-common php7.3-curl php7.3-fpm php7.3-gd php7.3-intl php7.3-json php7.3-mbstring php7.3-mysql php7.3-opcache php7.3-readline php7.3-xml php7.3-zip`

And my Nginx Configuration is coming from Digital Oceans nginxconfig.io

mydomain.com.conf

`
location ~ .php$ {
        # 404
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

```
# default fastcgi_params
include fastcgi_params;

# fastcgi settings
fastcgi_pass            unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index           index.php;
fastcgi_buffers         8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size     32k;

# fastcgi params
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT     $realpath_root;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE   "open_basedir=$base/:/usr/lib/php/:/tmp/";
```

}
`

Full config:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/nginx#?0.domain=mydomain.com&0.non_www=false&0.wordpress&php_server=%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fphp%2Fphp7.3-fpm.sock

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you strip it down - no plugins and just a default theme, then see if you get the error.  Also wou can add the following code to your functions.php file to show explicit error information.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// - Display Errors
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 0);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// - Error Reporting
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
error_reporting(-1);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// - Shutdown Handler
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function ShutdownHandler()
{
    if(@is_array($error = @error_get_last()))
    {
        return(@call_user_func_array('ErrorHandler', $error));
    };

    return(TRUE);
};

register_shutdown_function('ShutdownHandler');

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// - Error Handler
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function ErrorHandler($type, $message, $file, $line)
{
    $_ERRORS = Array(
        0x0001 => 'E_ERROR',
        0x0002 => 'E_WARNING',
        0x0004 => 'E_PARSE',
        0x0008 => 'E_NOTICE',
        0x0010 => 'E_CORE_ERROR',
        0x0020 => 'E_CORE_WARNING',
        0x0040 => 'E_COMPILE_ERROR',
        0x0080 => 'E_COMPILE_WARNING',
        0x0100 => 'E_USER_ERROR',
        0x0200 => 'E_USER_WARNING',
        0x0400 => 'E_USER_NOTICE',
        0x0800 => 'E_STRICT',
        0x1000 => 'E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR',
        0x2000 => 'E_DEPRECATED',
        0x4000 => 'E_USER_DEPRECATED'
    );

    if(!@is_string($name = @array_search($type, @array_flip($_ERRORS))))
    {
        $name = 'E_UNKNOWN';
    };

    return(print(@sprintf("%s Error in file \xBB%s\xAB at line %d: %s\n", $name, @basename($file), $line, $message)));
};

$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("ErrorHandler");
```

Comment: After the script update "E_WARNING Error in file  class-phpass.php  at line 68: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect.", I fixed it but still same issue is on going. Thank you for the script.